# How to make Last restart command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to know how I can get the time of the last restart of my discord.js bot.

Version: discord.js v14.7.2

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Client#uptime`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=uptime) that returns the time elapsed (in milliseconds) since the last time your bot entered the `ready` state.

If you subtract this value from the current time, you will get the time of the last restart:

```js
let restartTime = new Date(new Date() - client.uptime).toLocaleString(
  'en-GB',
  { dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'medium' },
);
console.log(`Bot was last restarted on ${restartTime}`);
// => Bot was last restarted on 18 December 2022 at 09:31:45
```

Comment: Hey, Its showing a error ```Invalid date``` Not in console but in the embed..

Comment: Probably `new Date() - client.uptime ` is `NaN`. Can you post your full code on a site like pastebin.com and paste the link here so I could take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7xmbR4VW

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is you missed a lot of things from your code (e.g. still don't know if `client` is correct).

Comment: Thats not the problem according to me, only problem is the reason for displaying Invalid date.

Comment: Wait, is that all your code? In that case you should move `let restartTime...` inside `execute`